# Kendo Combo Box Scroll: automatically call function

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am new to Kendo and creating a project using it. I have encountered a very unique kind of problem. I am using select options in kendoCombox. What I am doing is that I am just updating the select box value on click of the edit button. The value is updated successfully but when I scroll, it automatically calls the function where I get all values. Here is my code:

I am updating the value using this:

```
$("#rackModelName").data("kendoComboBox").value(deviceModelName);

<select class="span12"  onchange="rackChange()" id="rackModelName" name="rackModelName"
                                    tabindex="6">
                                    </select>
```

The below function automatically calls on scroll change:

```
function getRackFun(libraryDeviceId,dataCenterId,type){
        console.log("calling");
        if(libraryDeviceId && dataCenterId){
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            dataType : "json",
            url : "${getRacksByLocationId}&libraryDeviceId=" + libraryDeviceId+"&dataCenterId=" +dataCenterId,
            success : function(result) {

                if(result.length>0){
                var jsonObject = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(result));
                $("#rackModelName").data("kendoComboBox").setDataSource(jsonObject);


            }else{
                if(type!="edit"){
                    $("#rackModelName").data("kendoComboBox").value("");
                    $("#rackModelName").val("");

                $("#rackModelName").data("kendoComboBox").setDataSource([]);    
                $("#rackStartUnit").empty();
                $("#rackStartUnit").append($('<option>',{
                                            value : '',
                                            text : '<liferay-ui:message key="inventory.please_select"></liferay-ui:message>'
                                        }));
                $("#rackEndUnit").val('');
                }

            }
            }       

        });
        }else{
            $("#rackModelName").data("kendoComboBox").value("");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change the way you initialize the combobox to

```
$("#rackModelName").kendoComboBox({
...
change: rackChange, //your change function name
...

});
$("#rackModelName").data("kendoComboBox").value(deviceModelName);
```

remove the on change from the html element

To know more about events trigger check this https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/events